# Articles used interchangeably?

Tags: articles

As the definite article is used when we mention something for the second time or we mean the specific thing, would it be right to use the definite or indefinite article interchangeably before the noun ticket in the following conversation in the last example sentence 
(The dialog is from a movie)

Person 1: I don’t have enough money to get you a ticket (ticket was never mentioned before but they both know what ticket they mean)

Person2: I will do whatever it takes to get a ticket

Person 2:  You have to go Spider (a guy’s nickname) and then you will get A/THE ticket.

I know you could use your ticket but for the sake of the question I used ‘the’. 
I wonder if you could use ‘The’ or ‘a’ interchangeably
also, is it right to use ‘the’ when you don’t really mean the specific ticket ( that you can see and touch, etc) but use it because ‘the concept of a ticket’ is introduced in the conversation?

Likewise in the scenario below, the use of the article before the Cambridge Test in the last example sentence?

Person 1 says to Person 2: she wants to take a Cambridge English test.

After some time, the person 2 asks: So, does she still want to take THE  Cambridge test. (not the specific test in time and place you sit).

Because the idea of a Cambridge test was already introduced so the definite article is used, or you use THE because there is only one Cambridge test in the world?

Comment: 'The Cambridge test' is a particular example of an English test, so it's appropriate to use 'the'. In your first scenario it's less clear-cut. If you did choose to use 'the' it would mean 'the ticket that you need'.